# How can I remove union all from multiple selects and make it one single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write this in one single query. How can I do this?

Basically I need this for monthly so I can not write this 30 times. Any possible way to achieve please share. 
In below query same code is written 3 times but with different date parameter.

```
Select  
case when Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <  Cast(Getdate() as date)  then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6)) else 0 end AS [Opening],
case when Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <=  Cast(Getdate() as date)  then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6)) else 0 end AS [Closing]
from  [Item Ledger Entry] ILE
where Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <= Cast(Getdate() as date)

Union all

Select  
case when Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <  Cast(Getdate()-1 as date)  then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6)) else 0 end AS [Opening],
case when Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <=  Cast(Getdate()-1 as date)  then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6)) else 0 end AS [Closing]
from [Item Ledger Entry] ILE
where Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <= Cast(Getdate()-1 as date)

union all

Select  
case when Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <  Cast(Getdate()-2 as date)  then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6)) else 0 end AS [Opening],
case when Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <=  Cast(Getdate()-2 as date)  then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6)) else 0 end AS [Closing]
from [Item Ledger Entry] ILE
where Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <= Cast(Getdate()-2 as date)
```

---

Data will come like this in below picture .by using above query
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc6Co.png

Comment: Are you just looking for the previous 30 days of data because all you need to do then is change it to  'where Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <=  dateadd(dd,-30,getdate())' and do it in one query without any union whatsoever. You can cast it to a date to ignore time should you wish. I'd always use a dateadd to define a specific date between time periods.

Comment: what are you aiming at getting there, because you are potentially selecting the same records repeatedly, due to saying Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <= Cast(Getdate() as date) - will select any of the records in the next 2 SELECT's  At the moment it does not select records for one month

Comment: @Cato no his 2nd and 3rd queries take off 1 and 2 days respectively.

Comment: Doh correct it should be where Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) >= dateadd(dd,-30,getdate())' instead I can't edit it now

Comment: @RichCampbell - I think he needs to explain what he needs, it's a bit mind-bending

Comment: Hi @user - I think we need a better worked example, or some more notes - maybe you do just want the last 30 days, but your case statement is unclear

Comment: No this is not for last 30 day.In case of last 30 days it will show me sum of one month.  Here i want, example: My database started in 2010  so, from 01-01-2010 to 27-01-2018 i want sum, then it should stay as its then next day 01-01-2010 to 28-01-2018 sum , then next day 01-01-2010 to 29-01-2018 sum

Comment: Data will come like this in below picture .by using above query https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc6Co.png

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), ILE.[Posting Date], 120) where you group by on this for that month, if you need by day you would change the varchar(7) to varchar(10).  Remove the unions and just write a basic aggregate query.

***Note:*** You use this in your select section in your group by section as well, with the fields that you want to have broken down give you the right breakdown.

The case when and your range logic will also have to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DaysPast TABLE(
    Diff SMALLINT
)
DECLARE @MaxDaysPast SMALLINT=30;

WITH DaysPast(Diff) AS   
(  
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT Diff+1
    FROM DaysPast
    WHERE Diff<=@MaxDaysPast
)
INSERT INTO @DaysPast(Diff)
    SELECT *  
    FROM DaysPast  
    WHERE Diff<=@MaxDaysPast;

Select  
    case
        when Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <  Cast(DATEADD(DAYS,-1*dp.Diff,Getdate() as date)  then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6))
        else 0
    end AS [Opening],
    case
        when Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <=  Cast(DATEADD(DAYS,-1*dp.Diff,Getdate() as date)  then cast(ILE.Quantity as Numeric(19,6))
        else 0
    end AS [Closing]
from  [Item Ledger Entry] ILE
inner join @DaysPast dp ON Cast(ILE.[Posting Date] as date) <= Cast(DATEADD(DAYS,-1*dp.Diff,Getdate() as date)
```

Comment: Showing for 30 th , one row, Now if i run same on 1 st will it show 3o th and 1 st two rows

Comment: Maybe your source logic is bad. It probably should be =, not <=